# is it possible to get free ssl certificate for IIS on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, ssl, iis, https

I am using windows Azure virtual machine where I have hosted one nodejs application with the help of IIS.

The nodejs app is running fine but it runs with 'HTTP' and I want to use 'HTTPS'.

So, the case is that it currently runs on http://example.azurecloud.net and I want to make it https://example.azurecloud.net

In order to install ssl, I have installed AD CS (Active Directory Certification Service) on my windows AZURE machine and tried to create certificate but when I try to create a certificate with that service, it asks like "Specify online certification Authority" and there is option to select certification authority which is disabled for me and I am not able to create certificate.

[image]

So my questions are

1] Why I am not able to get any online certification authority list ?

2] Is it possible to obtain SSL certificates for free ? If yes then how ?

Comment: 2. Yes, https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: It is also possible to use a self signed certificate on your server and wrap it later with CloudFlare's free service and free certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what kind of SSL certificate you need. If you need a widely trusted one, mscdex and Lex Li have given you some suggestions where to get one. Simply search for "free SSL certificates".

For your purpose you do not need a certificate authority like AD CS. That would be to much work for just one certificate, that's not widely trusted.

If you do not need a widely trusted one you can create a certificate on your own. With Windows 2012 R2 and newer you have a PowerShell command called New-SelfSignedCertificate.

Example:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName example.azurecloud.net -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

After that you can select in IIS the new certificate in the web site's bindings:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the informatio Buddy!